# Unnable to make Google Cloud Messaging Work

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I followed the new tutorial [Implementing GCM Client on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), and I'm  unnable to make it work.

I get the token form my device succesfully, and when I send the following message

```
{
  "to": "f19jCbaw-S4:APA91b....",
  "notification": {
    "body": "body",
    "title": "title"
  },
  "data": {
    "message": "test"
  }
}
```

to https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send, I get the result:

```
{
"multicast_id": 844556567...,
"success": 1,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
{
"message_id": "0:1433092445706613%..."
}
]
}
```

But my app is never entering into the the onMessageReceived of MyGcmListenerService class. The only clue that I have is the following log trace:

```
 6399-6454/com.miapp.app W/GcmNotification﹕ Failed to show notification: Missing icon
```

I'm duplicated step by step the  [Google Cloud Messaging Quickstart](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) sample project. Obviusly I use my api key and my sender id... but id does not work, my app never stops in  my onMessageReceived method.

Anybody else is having this problem?

Comment: @Hidemburg: could you please show how you create the message on the php side ? I have a similar problem: 2 clients can send messages to each other but when I send a message from the server, php, nothing happens. I get a success result but nothing happens on the clients. Thanks.

Comment: I you get a success but you don't rceive the messages on the client side, then check twice your application_id (in build.gradle), and make sure that you are using the same application_id in your gradle script , on the google developer console, and the  google-services.json script. ANd of course, the application id has to be the same as your package structure (maybe you have changed your package structure after creating the project).

Comment: Yes, solved. I was just mistyping the php and also the icon was missing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact the payload without notification should reach the "onMessageReceived" method and work fine, but if the notification is present into the payload, the same error is displayed "Failed to show notification: Missing icon".

I tried to set the icon inside the AndroidManifest.xml (on the both intent-filter, on the receiver), but nothing worked.

If you do not require notification, just remove them from the payload.

And if you need the notification, you need to add another required field inside the notification:

If your icon is inside the mipmap you can add:

```
"icon" : "ic_launcher"
```

if your icon is inside the drawable, you should have:

```
"icon" : "@drawable/ic_myicon"
```

So your new request would look like:

```
{
  "to": "f19jCbaw-S4:APA91b....",
  "notification": {
    "body": "body",
    "title": "title",
    "icon" : "@drawable/ic_myicon"
  },
  "data": {
    "message": "test"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I will try what you say this evening. I suppose that you are right and this is the answer, and I will mark it as answer after testing it. Thanks again!